# Frequency Counter

Tags: powerbi, dax

Good evening everyone, I'm having trouble resolving the following question:

I have "Table 1" containing the occurrence records and "Table 2" containing the occurrences.

I need to set up a VIRTUAL TABLE or VIEW TABLE that presents the occurrences and their frequencies as follows:
[Tables with Perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3jnJ.png)

The most I could do was bring the occurrences with the total number of rows in the table, ie the same amount X for all.
[Last try using DaxStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbcov.png)

Comment: Where do you want the output? Are you creating a report to show the frequencies, or are you constructing a table in the data model?

Comment: Hi Kosuke i wanted reating a report to show the frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated your tables and here is the DAX for Table3 (perspectiva):

```
Table3 = 
VAR uniqueOccurences = DISTINCT(Table2[Occurence])
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(uniqueOccurences, 
        "count",  
            VAR currentOccurence = [Occurence]
            RETURN
            CALCULATE(COUNTA(Tabel1[ID]), 
                FILTER(Tabel1, CONTAINSSTRING(Tabel1[Occurences], currentOccurence) = TRUE()))
    )
```

This returns the following table:

[image: Table3 as calculated by above DAX]

Please mark this as the solution if this answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks so much Djerro, that was exactly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would your teaching be like if the occurrences were extratified?As below
https://imgur.com/U9jUEqy

Comment: UniqueOoccurrences should refer to Table2 as a whole as the new table is just Table2 plus a column. In the rest of the formula you need to change references to Occurrence to Secondary Occurences.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the solution so other people can find it easily. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a measure to show the numbers in the report.

But first, it is recommended to transform the table into a form like below, where each occurrence appears in each row. This has a lot of advantage to make the DAX measure simpler, more accurate, and run faster.

[image]

This can be easily achieved using Power Query Editor. The required steps are,

1. Select the comma delimited occurrences column.
2. In **Transform** tab, click **Split Column** and choose **By Delimiter**.
3. Make sure **Comma** and split at **Each occurrence of the delimiter** is selected by default.
4. In **Advanced options**, select split into **Rows**, then click **OK**.

Then you can define a measure to count the number of occurrences, which is as simple as below.

```
Count = COUNTROWS ( Tabela1 )
```

Now, in the report area, you can use the measure to obtain the desired output.

[image: Result]